# Sort values from a table based on hierarchy values of a field

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know how can i sort values from a table based on hierarchy values of a field.

EX:

```
A     B 
--------
1     A 
2     F
3     A
4     P
5     O
6     F
```

I would like sort the values by the B field and appear first the F Values, then A values, then P values and in the end the O values.

In the end, the result must be like this:

```
2   F
6   F
1   A
3   A
4   P
5   O
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `case` expression in `order by`.

```
select *
from tablename
order by case when B = 'F' then 1 
              when B = 'A' then 2 
              when B = 'P' then 3 
              when B = 'O' then 4 
          end, A
```

Answer (score 0):

More compact:

```
order by translate (B, 'FAPO', '1234')
```

This will also allow you, if needed (now or in the future) to have PF compared to PA, rather than just single letter values in column B.